# Switch Statement - Multiple results for single case

Tags: javascript, html, switch-statement

I have this page:

```js
var count = 0;

function switchStatement() {
  var text;
  var answers = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
  switch (answers) {
    case "":
      text = (count > 0) ? "You didn't type anything." : "Please type something down...";
      if (count < 1)
        count++;
      else
        count = 0;
      break;
    default:
      text = "Good job!";
  }
  document.getElementById("feedback").innerHTML = text;
  document.getElementById("userInput").value = "";
}
```

```html
<p>Please write something down and press "enter".</p>

<input id="userInput" type="text" onKeyDown="if(event.keyCode==13) switchStatement();">

<p id="feedback"></p>
```

When the user doesn't type anything before pressing "enter", (that's `case = "";`), a message will show up. If he does the same thing again, a different message will show up. If he does it a third time, it will loop back to the first message.

How can I add more messages to avoid having such a small loop? Say, if I wanted to have 5 different messages for when the user doesn't type anything, what should I change in my code?

Comment: Have an array of messages and index it on `count`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an array of messages :

```
var messages = ["message 1...", "message 2...", "message 3...", "message 4...", "message 5..."]
```

Then use the `count` variable as the `index` of this array to show the messages one after other.

**NOTE:** You must init the `count` to the default value `0` in case the user typed something so the next empty submit will show the first message in index `0`.

```js
var count = 0;
var messages = ["message 1...", "message 2...", "message 3...", "message 4...", "message 5..."];

function switchStatement() {
  var text;
  var answers = document.getElementById("userInput").value;

  switch (answers) {
    case "":
      text = messages[count];
      count = count < messages.length - 1 ? count + 1 : 0;
      break;
    default:
      text = "Good job!";
      count = 0;
  }
  document.getElementById("feedback").innerHTML = text;
  document.getElementById("userInput").value = "";
}
```

```html
<p>Please write something down and press "enter".</p>

<input id="userInput" type="text" onKeyDown="if(event.keyCode==13) switchStatement();">

<p id="feedback"></p>
```